# from google.cloud import monitoring_v3 ImportError: cannot import name monitoring_v3

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to utilize the Google Cloud Platform's Stack Driver API with the following Python/Flask code below...

**view.py**

```
import google.cloud
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
# from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import query
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.12.2
oauth2client==2.0.1
google-api-python-client==1.6.2
facebookads==2.11.1
httplib2==0.10.3
enum==0.4.6
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
google-auth
google-cloud-monitoring==0.28.0
google-cloud
```

For whatever reason it can't seem to find the `monitoring_v3` library as when whenever I run the code I am getting the following error...

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
ImportError: cannot import name monitoring_v3
```

I have tried to update to `google-cloud-monitoring==0.29.0` and that just churns out another non-related error.

Comment: Not many ideas, did you already tried [re-installing the libraries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries)?

Comment: @Carlos more times that I can count, my friend.

Comment: Maybe updating the [google-api-python-client (v1.7.3)](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/releases) and [google-clouud-python (v0.30.0)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/releases) to the lastest releases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading monitoring `0.29.0` to `1.1.0`

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-monitoring
```

Latest version now available is 2.0.0
https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

Could be a conflict (dependency or otherwise) between google-api-python-client and google-cloud*.

The former is a REST client which includes the monitoring API, the latter is gRPC based client.

Are you using 'google-api-python-client' for anything else?  If no, try removing that?

Comment: It's necessary that I use it. Also I tried removing the api client and it is throwing the same error. It doesn't appear to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your requirements.txt file is proper, and located in the source directory where you have the main.py.
If everything fails , copy a requirements.txt file from a working function , and replace the requirements modules in it (strangely this worked for me :P)